# Rigorous way of showing two domains are equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

How does one stringently show that a domain of the form $$a \le x \le b, f(x) \le y \le g(x)$$
is equal to another of the form $$c \le y \le d, u(y) \le x \le v(y)?$$
It's easy enough to do visually, but is there a way to do it by algebraically manipulaing above? Here's an example; $$0 \le y \le 2, 1-y \le x \le 1 $$
which is the same as $$-1 \le x \le 1, 1-x \le y \le 2$$.

Comment: What you want to do is prove $$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon 0\leq y\leq 2 \land -y\leq x\leq 1\}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon -1\leq x\leq 1\land -x\leq y\leq 2\}.$$ This can be done in a few ways. I'm not sure what you mean with *algebraic manipulation*, but in a strict sense such a thing isn't always easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, one might proceed like this: Note that $0\le y\le2,1-y\le x\le1$ is equivalent to the following four inequalities:
$$\begin{align}\tag1y&\ge0 \\\tag2y&\le2\\\tag3x&\le1\\\tag4x&\ge1-y\end{align}$$
whereas for $-1\le x\le1,1-x\le y\le 2$ we get
$$\begin{align}\tag5x&\ge-1 \\\tag3x&\le1\\\tag2y&\le2\\\tag8y&\ge1-x\end{align}$$
We immediately get $x\ge1-y\iff x+y\ge1\iff y\ge1-x$, so it only remains to show that $(1),(2),(3),(4)$ imply $(5)$ and that $(5),(2),(3),(8)$ imply $(1)$. And indeed
$$ x\stackrel{(4)}\ge 1-y\stackrel{(2)}\ge1-2=-1$$
and 
$$y\stackrel{(8)}\ge 1-x\stackrel{(3)}\ge1-1=0.$$
In fact, in this special case we might notie that both $(1)$ and $(5)$ are redundant, given the other three inequalities.